# d3 center bar chart's x-axis on arbitrary value

Tags: d3.js

I have a bar chart that is wider than the svg element but, with panning, you're able to drag left and right.  The x-axis is time based (I use `d3.time.scale()`).

After building the chart, I'd like to be able to pan to a specific point on the x-axis.  For example, the user may have already panned to a certain point and shut down their session - I'd like to put them back where they were when they return.

I've been looking at doing something like:

```
d3.selectAll('rect')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + savedXaxisLocation + ',0)';
```

Is that the right idea?  I'm assuming I also need to do that to the x axis itself?

As you can tell I'm feeling my way around this - I'd be happy to include any other code or screenshots if y'all feel it relevant.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would have a top-level `g` element that contains everything else and would translate that. This saves you from having to translate all the elements individually. When you do that, you may want to apply a [`clipPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) to hide the elements that have been panned out of view.

[This example](http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434) should help you to get a better idea of what you can do and how.

Comment: I think that using a containing `g` element is the right idea.  I have one already but it sets the clip-path and I was having clip-path issues transforming it.  I'm now adding another `g` element for transformations which looks promising.. in it I'll include my rects ("bars") and the x-axis.

Comment: Hmm.  I don't know if this approach will work although maybe I'm doing something wrong.  Right now, when I transform the enclosing `g` element, everything moves so that I have whitespace between the y-axis and the rest of the chart..

Comment: d3's panning feature actually transforms each individual element (bar) as well as the ticks on the x-axis but not the `path` element which is 'base line' of the x-axis.  That leads me to believe that I can't just put the x-axis in an enclosing `g`.

Comment: You can -- the panning feature doesn't rely on any particular setup. It might help if you could provide a complete example of what you're looking for.

Comment: If we use the example you provided: imagine panning the chart to the left so that "30" is the leftmost visible tick on the x-axis.  I'd like to be able to remember that and put the user back in the same place when they reload the page.

Comment: The value is retrieved towards the end of that file -- `self.downx = self.x.invert(p[0]);`.

Comment: After pouring over the code from the example, methinks it's all about resetting the domain of my x/xaxis

Comment: Say, Lars, in the example, do you know where the x's domain (`self.x.domain`) gets set?  I'm realizing that the domain is what's doing most of the work but I can't figure out how the domain is getting modified..it's not only modified by the `self.x.domain(new_domain)` line.  Maybe the zoom function?

Comment: Hmm.  Looks like it is the zoom function.  The [source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/behavior/zoom.js) calls a tidy little function called `rescale`..